Laravel 404 error for uploaded files: Static files not served
I am working with a Laravel project on a local development server using XAMPP (Apache). I am facing a problem where files uploaded to the `storage' directory are not served correctly. Specifically, when I try to access a file via its URL, I get a 404 not found error.
### Problem Description:
I am uploading the files to the `storage/app/public/documents' directory, and they seem to be uploaded successfully. However, when trying to access the files via the URL:
```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/documents/yourfile.pdf
```
I get a 404 not found error.
### Steps Taken:
1. **Symlink Checked:**
I ran the 'php artisan storage:link' command, and it showed that the encrypted link already exists.
2. **Verified File Upload:**
The file is located in the `storage/application/common/documents' directory.
3. **Directory Structure:**
The symbolic link `public/storage' points to `storage/app/public' as expected.
4. **Permission:**
I tried setting permissions using `chmod -R 755 repository` but it was not recognized on Windows. I checked the file permissions and they seem correct.
5. **Apache Configuration:**
Ensure that the Apache configuration allows serving static files. Here is the relevant part of `httpd.conf`:
``` apache
<Directory "D:/Academic Affairs/Hall Reservation/Hall Reservation-System 3/name/Hall-Book/Public" >
Let everything pass
All must be given
</Directory>
```
6. **.htaccess file:**
Verify that the `.htaccess' file in the ``public'' directory is set up correctly.
### Additional Information:
- **Server Setup:** XAMPP (Apache) on Windows.
- **Laravel version:** [specify your Laravel version]
- **File location:** `storage/app/public/documents/yourfile.pdf`
### Question:
What steps should I take to resolve this issue? Why can't files in the `storage' directory be accessed via the URL, even though the symbolic link is set correctly?
Any help or guidance to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Do you have the Options FollowSymLinks in your apache VirtualHost ?

"The file is located in the storage/application/common/documents directory" - than this file is not public. Your public uploaded files are in storage/app/public

You are not looking for file in right directory, try http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/application/common/documents/yourfile.pdf
